# Double subscript error in align

Tags: errors, align, amsmath, superscripts

What's the reason for the double superscript error?

`\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \hat{\textbf{\r}} + \frac{1}{r}                    \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \hat{\textbf{\phi}} + \frac{1}{r sin\phi}          \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \hat{\textbf{\theta}}`

Comment: This code will not produce a “double superscript” error, for the simple reason that there's no superscript at all.

Comment: How did you (re)define the macro `\r`? Is that where the double superscript error is originating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet doesn't bring a double superscript error. `align` is not used, also no alignment marker `&`.

However,

- `\r` would bring an error, I guess you (re)defined it
- you should not use `\textbf{\theta}` in math context. Instead, use `\boldsymbol` of `amsmath`. It even works for [bold Greek letters](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=3755).
- You should use `\sin` for the sine operator, so it would be upright, not italics like variables s, i, and n. You can even [define your own math operators](http://latex-community.org/know-how/latex/51-latex-math-science/207-defining-operators-like-sin-log-etc).

A compilable minimal example with those fixes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\r{R}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \hat{\textbf{\r}} +
  \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}} +
  \frac{1}{r \sin\phi} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
  \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Formula]